# Running GRASS GIS on Text-based interface alone

Tags: grass-gis, command-line

I'm required to run GRASS GIS functions on a CentOS 7 server using the GRASS Text-based interface as it is not possible to use the GUI. I basically want to import some shapefiles as vector layers and run a few network analysis functions. I wanted to see if the v.import command works but I just ended up with
`bash: v.import: command not found`

[image]

I'm fairly new to this so I'm not quite sure what I need to do. Is there no way to perform functions on a layer using the text based UI (CLI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old GRASS GIS version (6.4.4 from 2014!) which does not offer [v.import](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.import.html) as it was developed later.

Please change to GRASS GIS 7.x which is also available for CentoOS7. For this, see https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/linux/

Comment: I see, so once I update my GRASS version would I be able to run commands just as I would in the console of the GRASS GUI or is there more setting up that I need to do?

Comment: No extra settings needed, you just need to update.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm.